# Lotka-Volterra with logistic term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following predator-prey system
$$V'=rV(1-V/K)-aVP,$$ $$P'=-sP+abVP.$$ After some manipulations i end up with the adimensional system $$x'=x(1-\gamma x-y),$$ $$y'=y(-\beta+x),$$ where $\beta=s/r$ and $\gamma=r/(abK)$. I want to study the steady points, which are $(0,0), (1/\gamma,0)$ and $(\beta,1-\gamma\beta)$. From the jacobian matrix i can conclude that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point, but the other two points give me some difficult eigenvalues which i'm not able to classify. How can i study these points? Any help will be very appreciated. The jacobian matrix for the critical points are $$J(1/\gamma)=\begin{pmatrix} -1&-1/\gamma\\0&1/\gamma-\beta\end{pmatrix},$$ and $$J(\beta,1-\gamma\beta)=\begin{pmatrix}-\gamma\beta&-\beta\\1-\gamma\beta&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Are you able to classify them with any additional assumptions on $\beta$ and $\gamma$? It may be that they change behavior for different values of these parameters.

Comment: I want to classify them with the change of these parameters indeed

Comment: Could you perhaps post the eigenvalues for the other critical points so others don't have to reproduce your work? Also, this type of system is known as "Competitive Lotka-Volterra" in the literature if you want to look up previous work.

Comment: Recall that for $2\times 2$ matrices, stability can be completely determined by analyzing the signs of the trace an determinant of the Jacobian.

Comment: how is it? Any references?

Comment: Recall that $T = \mathrm{tr}(A) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ and that $D = \mathrm{det}(A) = \lambda_1\lambda_2$. The sign of $D$ tells you whether the eigenvalues have the same sign or not. If $D>0$ and $T<0$, then then both eigenvalues are negative and the system is stable.